# Async socket library for win 10 UAP/UWP (Universal App)?

Tags: c#, sockets, uwp

I want to asyncronly send the serialized protobuf data over a socket on an Win 10 UAP (to a desktop C# net app).
Is there any compatible library for that?
Fleck, SuperSocket, SignalR, ...
Noting is compatible with UAPs.
Not even the Socket.BeginConnect method is present in UAPs.
Is there a way to use async sockets on UAPs?

Comment: UAP should be Universal App. You would do something like that?:
`Stream streamOut = socket.OutputStream.AsStreamForWrite();
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(streamOut);
byte[] binary = touch.ToByteArray();
string binaryString = GetString(binary);
await writer.WriteLineAsync(binaryString);
await writer.FlushAsync();`
looks ugly to me.

Comment: SignalR is compatible with UWP platform, just get it using NuGet on aspnetwebstacknightly channel

Comment: Which package exactly? On aspwebstacknighly there is only version v2.2.1-pre... On nuget.org is v2.2.0. Both return "Some packages are not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x86-aot)."

Comment: @pythonimus hi ^^ how're you using Protobuf within a UWP app?

Answer (score 1):

Fleck and SuperSocket are not compatible with UWP App. But, the [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR) has added support for UWP app, but the Nuget package is not generated to support UWP, so we need to compile it by ourselves, here are the steps:

1. Download Source Codes of [SignalR in GitHub](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR).
2. Open `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.sln` with your VS (there will be a few popups suggesting you installing SilverLight and Windows 8 SDK, You can ignore them).
3. Find 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.UWP' Project->Properties->Click `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.UWP.rd.xml`->In the Properties Window below change Build Action Value from `Content` to `Embedded Resouce`:
   [image]
4. Build 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.UWP' with release AnyCPU mode. Find the output file: `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.dll` under `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.UWP\bin\x86 or x64\Release`
5. reference the dll file in your own Project.

Now you can use SignalR in your UWP Project.

Comment: I realized that the SignalR self-host/server does not work on UWP apps (only client, which is available without self compiling on aspwebstacknighly). So I stopped working with it.

Comment: Isnt SelfHosting SignlarR on Owin going to be supported in UWP apps? I Currently have an wpf application using this, and was thinking about migrating to UWP. Cant find any documentation on the issue. Is there a work around?